# Know 3D rotations from 2D projection transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projective-geometry, matrix-decomposition, affine-geometry

I have a projector that might move in 3D space, It will project to 2D plane, so I have a 2D image (as projection result), When I move the projector in one or all 3D axis (rotation-X, rotation-Y, rotation-Z), it produces rotation, shear on the 2D projected image. As well when I change FOV of the projector (vertical and horizontal), it produces a scaling on the 2D projected image. Now what I can know is the transformation matrix (affine or perspective) between projected images, before and after projector moving. My question is : using the transformation matrix, how can I estimate angles of rotations in 3D space and the angles of FOV of the projector after moving it in the space? As shown in the attached schema [image]

Comment: Your camera motion produces *shear*?! How strange. There are definitely ways to compute the fundamental matrix between the two views and then extract the relative rotation and translation. Have you had a look at those?

Comment: Search the web for “pose estimation” to find literature relevant to this. Might be worthwhile to also think about this in terms of real degrees of freedom. A general projective transform (perspective) has 8 geometrically relevant degrees of freedom (3×3 matrix modulo scalar multiples thereof). Your body movement presumably has 3 rotation + 3 translation + 1 FOV in which case you have an overdetermined problem. But if you also allow for movements of the picture sensor within its plane (2 RDoF), you are underdetermined. So what is your camera concept?

Comment: @rschwieb,Yes.. rotation of projector in the 3D space can project an 2D image with shear. It's a projector not camera.So how can we extract relative rotation and translation in 3D using the fundamental matrix ? could you indicate some methods that I can search for? thanks

Comment: @MvG: thanks for your proposition, I think  "pose estimation" is a proper method, but my case is a projector not camera, where I have no any information about neither focal length nor intrinsic params, I have only angles of FOV (vertical and horizontal) by degree. I think "pose estimation" needs some of these parameters. 
Projective transform can be computed from two projected 2D images before and after the movement of projector. but after this step I don't know how to extract the related 3Rot + 3T + FOV on the projector in the space.